# What does X_set[y_set == j, 0] mean?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

Recently, I have been following a tutorial where I came up with the following code

```
for i, j in enumerate(np.unique(y_set)):
    plt.scatter(X_set[y_set == j, 0], X_set[y_set == j, 1],
        c = ListedColormap(('red', 'green'))(i), label = j)
```

here, `y_set` is a vector having binary values `0`, `1` and `X_set` is an array with two columns.
I am specifically not understanding how to interpret the following line of code

```
X_set[y_set == j, 0], X_set[y_set == j, 1]
```

Comment: We pretty sure the `y_set == j, 0` will return `True` or `False`. And then, If your X_set defined by pandas type. we'll filter by boolean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few things going on here. For now, I will drop the loop but we know that `j` will take values in `y_set` so will be either zero or one. First make the two arrays:

```
import numpy as np

X_set = np.arange(20).reshape(10, 2)
y_set = np.array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1])
```

From the above, this code is basically doing:

```
plt.scatter(filtered_values_in_first_column_of X_set, 
            filtered_values_in_second_column_of X_set)
```

`y_set` is providing the filter. We can get there by building up the steps:

```
print("Where y_set == 0: Boolean mask.")
print(y_set == 0)
print()

print("All rows of X_set indexed by the Boolean mask")
print(X_set[y_set == 0])
print()

print("2D indexing to get only the first column of the above")
print(X_set[y_set == 0, 0])
print()
```

You can see more on the [`numpy` indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) here. Once you break the steps down, it's not too complicated but I think it was an unnecessarily complex way of achieving this task.

The `for` loop is so that they could repeat the plot with two different colours depending on whether the values are filtered by `y_set` being equal to 0 or 1.

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful.

Comment: It was a tutorial on logistic regression classification for machine learning